# Mysterious C# error in Unity when trying to return switch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement

I was following a YouTube tutorial about Minecraft-style terrain generation in Unity, and during part 10 of the tutorial, a script is written that contains a function that ends in a `return x switch` statement. The exact contents of the switch are as follows:

```
    public static Vector3Int GetVector(this Direction direction)
    {
        return direction switch
        {
            Direction.up => Vector3Int.up,
            Direction.down => Vector3Int.down,
            Direction.right => Vector3Int.right,
            Direction.left => Vector3Int.left,
            Direction.forward => Vector3Int.forward,
            Direction.backwards => Vector3Int.back,
            => throw new Exception("Invalid direction provided.")
        };
    }
```

`Direction` is an enum in a separate script that contains `forward`, `right`, `backwards`, `left`, `up`, and `down`, in that exact order.
The issue is that once the code is compiled, I receive this error in Unity from DirectionExtensions.cs (the script that contains the return switch):

> Assets/Scripts/Terrain/DirectionExtensions.cs(17,52): error CS8504: Pattern missing

I've tried searching for the error code and error message on Google, but the results are either reference materials such as lists of C# error messages, or unrelated Unity errors. I've found no real-world example of this error ever occurring. And no, the error is not expected, and thus the tutorial does not demonstrate how to fix it at any point. how can I resolve this error so I can continue working on my project?

Comment: You need an underscore before `=>`, so `_ => ,,,` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching

Comment: `Mysterious C# error`s usually mean exactly what they are saying ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `discard` to catch all cases not matched by the previous patterns:

```
public static Vector3Int GetVector(this Direction direction)
{
    return direction switch
    {
        Direction.up => Vector3Int.up,
        Direction.down => Vector3Int.down,
        Direction.right => Vector3Int.right,
        Direction.left => Vector3Int.left,
        Direction.forward => Vector3Int.forward,
        Direction.backwards => Vector3Int.back,
        _ => throw new Exception("Invalid direction provided.")
    };
}
```

Notice the underscore at

```
_ => throw new Exception("Invalid direction provided.")
```

The [documentation (Pattern matching with switch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards#pattern-matching-with-switch) explains:

> The discard pattern can be used in pattern matching with the switch expression. Every expression, including null, always matches the discard pattern.

Comment: I think I actually saw the underscore in the tutorial script, but must have passed it off as weird syntax highlighting and forgot to include it. Thanks for letting me know that the underscore is an actual character that's meant to be included in the script!